# AWS Appstream Alternative

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, remoteapp

I'm wondering if there is a suitable alternative to AWS Appstream offered through Azure services. Previously Azure RemoteApp seemed to fit the bill, however it looks like support for this feature is waning and Microsoft is pushing toward Citrix Apps.

I'd like to be able to set up an application and publish it (available via a web browser if possible) for internal and external users to access.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish remote applications in Windows Virtual Desktop.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/publish-apps

We have an online learning path that walks you through all the features.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/m365-wvd/